# tailwind breaktpoints for <th> not working

Tags: breakpoints, tailwind-css

I want the columns of a table to be a bit wider on small screens (so that the icons I use in them are still a decent size)

I'm doing :

````html
<th  style="width:41% sm:width:35%" class="py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                      Name/No
                    </th>
                    <th style="width:3% sm:width:5% " ></th>
                    <th style="width:3% sm:width:5% " ></th>
                    <th style="width:3% sm:width:5% " ></th>```

but it only uses the 5% not the 3% no matter how big my window is

PS there are some other <th> before this so the total percentage = 100%
````

Answer (score 1):

First of, `sm` **cannot** be used inside style.

[table-fixed](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/table-layout#fixed) - You can manually set the widths for some columns.

Use [break-words](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break#break-words) to add line breaks mid-word if needed.

```
<table class="table-fixed w-full">
  <thead>
    <tr class="break-words">
      <th class="bg-gray-100 w-40 sm:w-auto">Title</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Author</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views2</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views3</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views4</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views5</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views6</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views7</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views8</th>
      <th class="bg-gray-100">Views9</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Checkout this [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VetpGFgmuh)